# Uncaught TypeError: .draggable is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I don't know what is wrong here, it has already driven me nuts. Whenever I use some breakpoints on the code, as in the image, and reload the page then everything works fine. But if I close the developer tools and then I refresh, it throws me this error: 'Uncaught TypeError: $design[a].draggable is not a function(…)'.

Following is my code and the images:

Debugging image:

[image]

My script:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas = $("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

    var design = [];
    var $design = [];
    var pic = [];

    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: ('/getCustomizeParts'),
      data: {
      },
      success: function(data) {
        for (var a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
          design[a] = new Image();
          pic[a] = data[a].partimagePath;
          design[a].src = "images/part/" + pic[a];
          $design[a] = $("#design" + (a + 1));
          //here it threows me the error
          $design[a].draggable({
            helper: 'clone',
          });
          $design[a].data("image", design[a]);
        }
        $canvas.droppable({
          drop: dragDrop,
        });
      }
    });
```

I have included the script tags in my page in following order

```
<script src="/Admin/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Admin/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Admin/js/customizeScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: A common cause of this error is loading multiple versions of jQuery.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much i think that was the issue now its loading fine

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the **defer** attribute to your script link as following:

```
<script src="/Admin/js/customizeScript.js" defer></script>
// or this for XHTML
<script src="/Admin/js/customizeScript.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

see [this w3school page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp) for more info about the defer attribute

Comment: That's useful if the problem is that it's not finding DOM elements. But the error is about not finding a function.

Comment: It is not finding a function that is provided by another script tag, in this case waiting other script tags to finish rendering will be useful, don't you think so?

Comment: Scripts are loaded synchronously by default. So the third script doesn't run until the 2nd script finishes loading.

Comment: You said it "loading", not executing. So some functions in the library won't be ready yet to use (the execution hasn't reached it yet), so if a script in the third tag uses a function that isn't registered yet (racing condition) it will throw a similar error.

Comment: Loading a script executes it. There is no race condition, it's all synchronous.

Comment: Millions of web pages load jQuery and jQuery UI without the `defer` attribute, and they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely caused because your page has not completed loading yet, so one of your **js** files isn't there yet, try running your code after the document gets ready.

You can do that by adding your code to the **$(document).ready** function, one of the ways to do that is as following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // your code here
})
```

Comment: Nope I searched the interent and used this this did not worked.

Comment: From what I see, your are separating your code in a file. Did you try to put the whole files content in the document.ready function?

Comment: Scripts loaded with `<script>` are loaded synchronously unless you use the `async` attribute, so you don't need to use `$(document).ready()` to wait for scripts to load. That's only necessary to wait for DOM elements.

Comment: Yes, but if the async keyword isn't present, the contents of the file will be executed directly when the js file is loaded, so if the previous file is larger (which is in this case) it might not be executed yet! so waiting until the document is ready is safer in my opinion

Comment: The third JS file won't be executed until after the first and second JS files are completely executed. If you couldn't depend on that, then you couldn't use `$(document).ready()`, since that requires jquery to be completely loaded.